# Python - Calculate the difference between two datetime.time objects

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have two datetime.time objects and I want to calculate the difference in hours between them. For example

```
a = datetime.time(22,00,00)
b = datetime.time(18,00,00)
```

I would like to be able to subtract these so that it gives me the value 4.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To calculate the difference, you have to convert the `datetime.time` object to a `datetime.datetime` object. Then when you subtract, you get a `timedelta` object. In order to find out how many hours the `timedelta` object is, you have to find the total seconds and divide it by `3600`.

```
# Create datetime objects for each time (a and b)
dateTimeA = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), a)
dateTimeB = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), b)
# Get the difference between datetimes (as timedelta)
dateTimeDifference = dateTimeA - dateTimeB
# Divide difference in seconds by number of seconds in hour (3600)  
dateTimeDifferenceInHours = dateTimeDifference.total_seconds() / 3600
```

Answer (score 14):

This is how I did

```
a = '2200'
b = '1800'
time1 = datetime.strptime(a,"%H%M") # convert string to time
time2 = datetime.strptime(b,"%H%M") 
diff = time1 -time2
diff.total_seconds()/3600    # seconds to hour
```

output: 4.0

Answer (score 3):

I got my result from this problem:

```
a='2017-10-10 21:25:13'

b='2017-10-02 10:56:33'

a=pd.to_datetime(a)

b=pd.to_datetime(b)

c.total_seconds()/3600
```

but in series that wont work:

```
table1['new2']=table1['new'].total_seconds()/3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside, but this might bother more users finding this question...

To calculate the difference between pandas columns, better is not to have time as type `datetime.time` in the first place, but as `numpy.timedelta64` instead (duration since midnight). One way to fix this:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
for c in df.select_dtypes('object'):
    if isinstance(df[c][0], time):
        df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda t: datetime.combine(date.min, t) - datetime.min)
```