# subtract dataframe times get hours as floating point

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

Input file "clockTimes2020-40.xlsx" is CSV.  Times are in columns.
I want to calculate the time difference, "dur", as number of hours in float float, but I get the error message indicated.

```
import pandas
import datetime
print('pandas.__version__:',pandas.__version__)
df = pandas.read_excel('clockTimes2020-40.xlsx', sheet_name='clockTimes2020-40')
line0 = df.loc[0]
print('line0: ',line0)
print('line0 type is ',type(line0))
beg = line0[4]
end = line0[5]
print('beg = ',beg, 'type: ',type(beg))
print('end = ',end, 'type: ',type(end))
dur = end - beg
print('dur = ',dur,'type:',type(dur))
```

RESULTS
runfile('C:/Users/Muir/ABCorp/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Muir/ABCorp')
pandas.**version**: 1.1.3
line0:  CID                        1
Lname                  Adams
Fname              Francis J
Mon      2020-09-28 00:00:00
Moin                08:00:10
Moout               17:16:24
Tue      2020-09-29 00:00:00
Tuin                07:58:41
Tuout               16:55:55
Wed      2020-09-30 00:00:00
Wein                07:53:00
Weout               17:45:45
Thu      2020-10-01 00:00:00
Thin                07:53:00
Thout               17:45:45
Fri      2020-10-02 00:00:00
Frin                07:53:00
Frout               16:59:45
Sat      2020-10-03 00:00:00
Sain                00:00:00
Saout               00:00:00
Sun      2020-10-04 00:00:00
Suin                00:00:00
Suout               00:00:00
Name: 0, dtype: object
line0 type is  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
beg =  08:00:10 type:  <class 'datetime.time'>
end =  17:16:24 type:  <class 'datetime.time'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Muir\ABCorp\untitled0.py", line 21, in 
dur = end - beg
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

Comment: `.xlsx` is not a csv :-)

Comment: @user3338092 , print(((end.hour*3600  + end.minute *60 + end.second ) -    ( beg.hour*3600 + beg.minute *60 + beg.second )) /3600.)

Answer (score 0):

[Python - Calculate the difference between two datetime.time objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305577/python-calculate-the-difference-between-two-datetime-time-objects/43308104)

To calculate the difference, you have to convert the datetime.time object to a datetime.datetime object. Then when you subtract, you get a timedelta object. In order to find out how many hours the timedelta object is, you have to find the total seconds and divide it by 3600.

```
# Create datetime objects for each time (a and b)
dateTimeA = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), a)
dateTimeB = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), b)
# Get the difference between datetimes (as timedelta)
dateTimeDifference = dateTimeA - dateTimeB
# Divide difference in seconds by number of seconds in hour (3600)  
dateTimeDifferenceInHours = dateTimeDifference.total_seconds() / 3600
```

Comment: dur=((end.hour*3600  + end.minute *60 + end.second ) -    ( beg.hour*3600 + beg.minute *60 + beg.second )) /3600.   did the job.  THANKS ALL

Answer (score 0):

**#EDIT [Solved]:**

```
dur=((end.hour*3600  + end.minute *60 + end.second ) -    ( beg.hour*3600 + beg.minute *60 + beg.second )) /3600.
```

Else, you can **Convert** "TIME" as *string* to *datetime* type.

Then you can get "time" in **float hours** by using **total_seconds()/3600**.

Look at this Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
beg = '08:00:10'
end = '17:16:24' 

dur = datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(beg, '%H:%M:%S')

result = dur.total_seconds()/3600

print(result)
```